# Scale parameter value to extract precipitation data using CHIRPS in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, precipitation

I'm trying to find the precipitation data over 270 polygons using the UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/PENTAD collection. When I set the scale anywhere between 10m-1000m, I can see for all polygons there is data through the period. But when the scale is to CHIRPS' native resolution of 5566m, only for a few polygons precipitation data is found.

```
var aoi = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/ypm-rs-ml/assets/land');

var startDate= '2017-1-01'
var endDate = '2018-1-1'

var imageCollection = 'UCSB-CHG/CHIRPS/PENTAD'
var bandName = 'precipitation'
var resolution = 5566     //in meters

var collection = ee.ImageCollection(imageCollection)
                    .filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate, endDate))
                    .select(bandName);
                              
var zonal_stats_rainfall = collection.toBands()
                            .reduceRegions({
                               collection: aoi,
                               reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                               scale: 10m, // or 5566 ?
                            })    

Export.table.toDrive({collection: zonal_stats_rainfall, 
                    description:'rainfall', 
                    folder:'try', 
                    fileNamePrefix: 'rainfall', 
                    fileFormat: 'CSV'})
```

Is it ok, to set the scale to 10m here? I will be using this information along with information gathered using Sentinel 2 collection further.

Asset: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ypm-rs-ml/assets/land

(If this helps, each polygon has a unique property called 'Name').

Comment: `projects/ypm-rs-ml/assets/YPM_160_final` isn't shared.

Comment: @DanielWiell asset link is added.

Comment: Here's how to share an asset: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/asset_manager#sharing-assets

Comment: Sorry, I missed selecting the Anyone can read option. It's done now.